# Selecting records with both of the two columns have 0 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I have this data frame of many records with columns, let's say, from 'a' to 'z'.

I need to find the number of records in which both ['a'] = 0 and ['z'] = 0.

I was told to use `crosstab` but I've taken a look at the documentation and I didn't understand a thing.

How can I find the number of records in which both ['a'] = 0 and ['z'] = 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sum` to count row that matches your conditions:

```
>>> df
    a  z
0   4  3
1   2  2
2   1  4
3   4  2
4   2  2
5   1  1
6   0  0  <- True
7   0  2
8   4  3
9   0  0  <- True
10  3  4
11  2  0
12  4  1
13  0  0  <- True
14  1  0
15  1  4
16  3  1
17  2  1
18  4  3
19  0  2

>>> sum((df['a'] == 0) & (df['z'] == 0))
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to filter the rows with your conditions:

```
df.loc[(df['a'] == 0) & (df['z'] == 0)]
```

If you want to get the count of rows with such conditions, you can use:

```
df.loc[(df['a'] == 0) & (df['z'] == 0)].shape[0]
```