# Computing a number table for two types of records in Panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame of many records with columns, let's say, from 'a' to 'z' in pandas.

I need to build a table of 4 cells with the numbers of records that have 'a' = 0 and 'z'= 0, 'a' = 0 and 'z' != 0, 'a' != 0 and 'z' = 0, 'a' != 0 and 'z' != 0.

What is the best Pythony-pandas way to do it? I can compute the four sums doing indexing and summing, but I'm sure there should be a built-in elegant way of doing it.

What is that way?

Comment: Maybe show us some sample data~

Comment: @BENY -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/68026056/15239951

Answer (score 2):

You can group by the values of whether each column is 0 and get the size of these groups:

```
>>> df.groupby([df['a'] == 0, df['z'] == 0]).size()
a      z    
False  False    19
       True      2
True   False     4
dtype: int64
```

Alternately you can also create a 2-column dataframe with these series and use `value_counts` which yields the same result:

```
>>> pd.concat([df['a'] == 0, df['z'] == 0], axis='columns').value_counts()
a      z    
False  False    19
True   False     4
False  True      2
dtype: int64
```

Calling this result `counts` we can then simply unstack if you want a 2 by 2 table:

```
>>> counts.unstack('z', fill_value=0)
z      False  True 
a                  
False     19      2
True       4      0
```

In the first level of `counts`’ index, or the index in the 2x2 table, `True` means `a == 0` and `False` means `a != 0`. In the second level or columns, `True` means `z == 0`. In this sample data no rows have `a == 0` and `z == 0` at the same time.

If you want to generically rename them you can do something like this:

```
>>> for level, name in enumerate(counts.index.names):
...     counts.rename({True: f'{name} == 0', False: '{name} != 0'}, level=level, inplace=True)
>>> counts
a       z     
a != 0  z != 0    19
a == 0  z != 0     4
a != 0  z == 0     2
dtype: int64
>>> counts.unstack('z', fill_value=0)
z       z != 0  z == 0
a                     
a != 0      19       2
a == 0       4       0
```

Alternately to flatten the index to a single level, and this also works generically with any number of variables:

```
>>> counts.index = counts.index.map(lambda tup: ' & '.join(f'~{var}' if truth else var for truth, var in zip(tup, counts.index.names)))
>>> counts
a & z     19
~a & z     4
a & ~z     2
```

Comment: I like the last crosstab with unstack. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
a = df['a'] == 0
z = df['z'] == 0

count = pd.Series([sum(a & z), sum(a & ~z), sum(~a & z), sum(~a & ~z)],
                  index=['a & z', 'a & ~z', '~a & z', '~a & ~z'])
```

```
>>> count
a & z       3
a & ~z      2
~a & z      2
~a & ~z    13
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), as follows:

```
a = df['a'] == 0
z = df['z'] == 0

count_tab = pd.crosstab(a, z, rownames=["'a' = 0 ?"], colnames=["'z' = 0 ?"])
```

**Result:**

```
print(count_tab)


'z' = 0 ?  False  True 
'a' = 0 ?              
False         13      2
True           2      3
```